# Problem with "while not loop" in Python code

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I create a simple code in Phyton, it demands two numbers and until are given you´re in a loop (because the code checks if an int number is given). After that, you have to choose a certain operation. But my code can´t break the `loop`. I don´t know what´s wrong, if it is the indentation? If I shouldn't use a loop in this, the syntax?

```
dataRight = False

#Check if the data are int numbers

while not dataRight:
  print("Convert LightYears and Parsecs, enter the data:")
  dataParsec = input("Parsecs Number: ")

  try:
    dataParsec = int(dataParsec)

  except:
    dataParsec = "Error1"

  dataLight = input("LightYear Númber: ")
  try:
    dataLight = int(dataLight)

  except:
    dataLight = "Error2"
    if dataParsec != "Error1" and dataLight != "Error2":
        dataRight = True

#After the data given is right, choose the operation to make.

question = input("Choose, A)-LightYear to Parsecs, B)-Parsecs to LightYear: ")
question = question.upper()
lightYear = 3.26156

if question == "A":
  convertlightYear = dataParsec / lightYear
  print("Convert to Parsecs: ", str(convertlightYear))
elif question == "B":
  convertParsec = dataParsec * lightYear
  print("Convert to LightYear: ", str(convertParsec))
else:
  print("Data entered is wrong")
```

Can someone help me? It's been days and I can´t see what´s wrong.

Comment: Have you tried unindenting 'if dataParsec != "Error1" and dataLight != "Error2":' one level?  It's currently indented under an except and I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and didn´t work. :C

Answer (score 1):

##### Code:

- As far as I understood, your problem is non-terminating `while loop`. It's just because of indentation.

```
while not dataRight:
  print("Convert LightYears and Parsecs, enter the data:")
  dataParsec = input("Parsecs Number: ")

  try:
    dataParsec = int(dataParsec)

  except:
    dataParsec = "Error1"

  dataLight = input("LightYear Númber: ")
  try:
    dataLight = int(dataLight)

  except:
    dataLight = "Error2"
  # This must be outside the except that's all
  if dataParsec != "Error1" and dataLight != "Error2":
    dataRight = True
```

##### Output:

```
Convert LightYears and Parsecs, enter the data:
Parsecs Number: l
LightYear Númber: 5
Convert LightYears and Parsecs, enter the data:
Parsecs Number: 2
LightYear Númber: 5
Choose, A)-LightYear to Parsecs, B)-Parsecs to LightYear: A
Convert to Parsecs:  0.613203497712751
```

Comment: Didn´t work either. I´m missing something...

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to stay in the loop until the user enters a number, try something along these lines

```
dataParsec = input("Parsecs Number: ")
while dataParsec.isdigit() == False:
  print("Convert LightYears and Parsecs, enter the data:")
  dataParsec = input("Parsecs Number: ")
```

Comment: Great! I had to change some of the code taking as an example what you post:

Comment: Nice! Hope it helped

Comment: Indeed! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This do the work:

```
print("Convert LightYears and Parsecs, enter the data:")

dataParsec = input("Parsecs Number: ")

while dataParsec.isdigit() == False:
  dataParsec = input("Parsecs Number: ")

dataLightYear = input("LightYears Number: ")

while dataLightYear.isdigit() == False:
  dataLightYear = input("LightYears Number: ")
  

question = input("Choose, A)-LightYear to Parsecs, B)-Parsecs to LightYear: ")
question = question.upper()
lightYear = 3.26156

if question == "A":
  convertlightYear = int(dataParsec) / int(dataLightYear)
  print("Convert to Parsecs: ", str(convertlightYear))
elif question == "B":
  convertParsec = int(dataParsec) * int(dataLightYear)
  print("Convert to LightYear: ", str(convertParsec))
else:
  print("Data entered is wrong")
```

Thanks Blckknght, Bibhav and Victor_G. All of you were of great Help! :D